# log4net: Identifying the entry assembly when using a dll in two different projects

Tags: c#, log4net

I'm trying to find a clean solution to this problem:
I have Project A and Project B both using a common dll.
assume common has a method called hello() that is writing something to the log

As I am writing to the log, I would like to write to the log an identification as to whether the call started from a dll in Project A or B.

Is that even possible ?

[one solution I thought of is to initialize the logger in the beginning sequence in A and B, and then store the logger in ThreadContext. but then the problem is that if a new thread is created, the logger would be lost)

Comment: How are you creating your logger(s) at present?

Comment: member variable in each class: m_logger = GetLogger<MyClassName>
so this means that writing to log from hello() will not include information as to whether the call came from A or B

Comment: If you used the _type_ as the name of the logger, that would include the name of the DLL via the namespace, i.e. `Company.ProjectA.Classes.Class1` vs `Company.ProjectB.Classes.Class2`

Comment: stuartd, thanks for your reply. as for the logger that would be initialized in the common dll, this fully qualified name would not contain neither ProjectA nor ProjectB. it will just contain Common.ClassName. I have added a solution to this problem for future reference down below.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding the %stacktrace{level} or %stacktracedetail{level} to you conversion pattern. This will give you the number of stackframes you define, in level in your trace. Assumed your types tell you what dll is making the call.

```
<conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline%stacktrace{3}" />
```

> stacktrace
>
> Used to output the stack trace of the logging event The
>   stack trace level specifier may be enclosed between braces. For
>   example, %stacktrace{level}. If no stack trace level specifier is
>   given then 1 is assumed Output uses the format: type3.MethodCall3 >
>   type2.MethodCall2 > type1.MethodCall1 This pattern is not available
>   for Compact Framework assemblies.
>
> stacktracedetail
>
> Used to output the
>   stack trace of the logging event The stack trace level specifier may
>   be enclosed between braces. For example, %stacktracedetail{level}. If
>   no stack trace level specifier is given then 1 is assumed Output uses
>   the format: type3.MethodCall3(type param,...) > type2.MethodCall2(type
>   param,...) > type1.MethodCall1(type param,...) This pattern is not
>   available for Compact Framework assemblies.